# Python FTP to iPad

Tags: python, ipad, ftp

I'm on Windows 7.

I cannot connect to my iPad with a simple Python script:

```
HOST = '192.168.1.122'
try:
    f = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
except (socket.error, socket.gaierror), e:    
    MessageBox.Show('ERROR: cannot reach "%s"' % HOST)
    return          
try:
    f.connect(HOST,2121)
    f.login()
except ftplib.error_perm:
    MessageBox.Show('ERROR: cannot login anonymously')
    f.quit()
    return
```

The errors I have is "getaddrinfo returns an empty list" and the "cannot reach..." message... Cannot solve it...

I tried to FTP with several programs on the iPad without success. If I FTP via DOS box or using a FTP software it works. I tried as well another FTP server on my PC and it works.

I am forced to use port 2121, so can't change it.

Any clue or experience?

Comment: Do you have an FTP server running on your iPad?

Comment: I would assume so considering he states it works using FTP software: `If i FTP via DOS box or using a FTP software it works`

Comment: I assume,that something like http://www.savysoda.com/WiFiFTP  is installed.

Comment: If FTP doesn't work, try to `telnet` to port 2121 to see if the iPad answers. If not, either it's not listening on that port (or at all), it's firewalled, or the iPad's IP address changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read docs before anything:

> class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[,
>   passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]]) Return a
>   new instance of the FTP class. When
>   host is given, the method call
>   connect(host) is made. When user is
>   given, additionally the method call
>   login(user, passwd, acct) is made
>   (where passwd and acct default to the
>   empty string when not given). The
>   optional timeout parameter specifies a
>   timeout in seconds for blocking
>   operations like the connection attempt
>   (if is not specified, the global
>   default timeout setting will be used).

So, if you do f = ftplib.FTP(HOST) it fails because it will try to connect to standard port (21) and not 2121.
You should get an instance of ftplib and later use f.connect(HOST, 2121).

http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html

Comment: yep, that's the thing. I read the docs, but I wouldn't be here if I could have gone through that alone, would I ? Thanks a lot, this really did the trick...

Comment: That's Ok Maurizio, just pointing about read the docs because (almost I) always 'try' before read... Glad to know that it worked now! Good Luck!